# How can you use a unary relationship on a specialized entity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-relationship, erd

I'm trying to create a table for the technician entity in the erd below (with mssql), is it posisble to use unary relationship in a specialized entity?

[image: ()]

This is my code but it gives this error : Number of referencing columns in foreign key differs from number of referenced columns, table `Technician`.

```
create table  Technician
(
    Tec_ID int Foreign key references Employee (id_employee),
    Primary key (Tec_ID),
    Foreign key references Technician (Tec_ID)
);
```

`id_employee` is the primary key of the employee entity of course. I wanted it to form a unary relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just need a foreign key column:

```
create table Technician
(
    Tec_ID int primary key references Employee(id_employee),
    Supervisor_ID int null references Technician(Tec_ID)
);
```

Assuming only Technicians supervise Technicians because you said you wanted a "unary" relationship.  Otherwise the foreign key would reference `Employee(id_employee)`.

Comment: yes, i meant to say that i a technician supervises other technicians thank u very much!